# How to declare multiple variables

Tags: ruby

1. I want to know how I can declare multiple variables. I typed `a,b=1` expecting to get `a=1,b=1`, but I got:

   ```
   a,b=1
   a #=> 1
   b #=> nil
   ```

   How am I able to do this?
2. After this code, I did:

   ```
   a="Hello "
   b=a
   c="World~"
   b << c
   b #=> "Hello World"
   ```

   Why is `b` the same as `a`'s value?

Comment: You can only ask one question at a time.  That's a firm rule. However, if you post Q2 as a separate question, someone will probably point out that `b=a` causes `a` and `b` to point to the same object (e.g., `a.object_id
 #=> 70270098990060; b.object_id; #=> 70270098990060`) so if the object is changed it will be reflected in the values of both `a` and `b`.

Comment: As well as `a=b=1`, there's also "parallel assignment": `a,b,c=1,2,3; [a,b,c]=>[1,2,3]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To declare multiple vars on the same line, you can do that:

```
a = b = "foo"
puts a # return "foo"
puts b # return "foo" too
```

About your second question, when doing `b << c`, you are assigning `c`'s value to `b`. Then, you are overriding previous value stored in `b`. Meanwhile, `a` keeps the same value because Ruby does not user pointers.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is called destructuring assignment. Basically, you take what is on the right side of the equals sign, and destructure it, or break it apart, and then assign each section to each corresponding variable on the left.

Ruby is super friendly, and is providing some syntactic sugar that might be confusing.

When you type this:

```
a, b = 1
```

You are really saying something closer to this:

```
[a, b] = [1, nil]
```

A good example of destructuring assignment can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). It's for JavaScript, but I like it because the syntax is very explicit about what is happen when you do such an assigment.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, in the case of

```
a, b, c = 1, 2
```

the runtime system works the following way:

```
a, b, c = [1, 2]

_result = ( a, b, c = (_values = [1, 2]) )

a = _values[0] # => 1

b = _values[1] # => 2

c = _values[2] # => nil

_result = _values # => [1, 2]
```

However, in the case of a single value on the right hand side: `a, b = 1`, the computation process looks a bit different:

```
_result = ( a, b = ( _value = (_values = [1]).first ) )

a = _values[0] # => 1

b = _values[1] # => nil

_result = _value # => 1
```

Can someone approve or disprove my assumption?